# Bound of integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that $u\geq 1$. Is there anyway to bound the following integral$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u^p\log u\,dx
$$
by something which depends on some power of $u$?

Comment: Fast decay at infinity, but $u\ge1$, are you sure?

Comment: I edited the question based on your comment. Thank you.

Comment: The integral can be finite only if $u\to1$ sufficiently fast at infinity. I don't think that can be expressed by powers of $u$.

Comment: How do I show that it can be finite?

Comment: I have heard about the logarithmic Sobolev inequalities, but it seems I can only use them by assuming $\int u^p\,dx=1$, which I can't in my context.